# Is Math.random() safe to use?

Tags: java, android, performance, recursion

I have a method which is generating random integers. I don't want integers to be repeated, so I created this code -

```
int prevInt = 0;

private int randomInt() {
    int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
    //generate random numbers between 0 to 3 inclusive

    if(random == prevInt)
        return randomInt();
    //if previous random number is equal to currently generated
    //random number, then call this method again for a different
    //random number

    prevInt = random;
    return random;
    //else return the generated random number
}
```

Is the above code safe to use? At worst case scenario, can it be possible that all random integers generated by `Math.random() * 3` are same?

Comment: The `Math.random` package is _not_ secure, q.v. this post: http://franklinta.com/2014/08/31/predicting-the-next-math-random-in-java/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I think he means safe as in won't run forever, not safe as in secure.

Comment: You can use java.security.SecureRandom if the numbers generated are for encryption purposes

Answer (score 1):

```
private final Random random = new Random();

private int randomInt(final int prev, final int max) {
  final int next = random.nextInt(max - 1);
  if(next >= prev){
    return next + 1;
  }else{
    return next;
  }
}
```

This will return an int between 0 and max without the need to repeat.

Comment: Please guys who-so-ever downvotes at least add a cmment that why you downvoted it.... Don't do it just for voting....

Answer (score 1):

```
public static double random()
```

Returns a **double** value with a **positive sign**, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

There are **two principal means of generating random** (really pseudo-random) numbers:

> 1. the Random class generates random integers, doubles, longs and so on,
>      in various ranges.
> 2. the static method Math.random generates doubles between 0 (inclusive)
>      and 1 (exclusive).

To generate random integers:

do not use `Math.random` (it produces doubles, not integers)
use the `Random` class to generate random integers between 0 and N.
To generate a series of random numbers as a unit, you need to use a single Random object - do not create a new Random object for each new random number.

Other alternatives are:

```
SecureRandom, a cryptographically strong subclass of Random
ThreadLocalRandom, intended for multi-threaded cases
```

please have a look at [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62) post.
[SO Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java),[Reference 2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

From the javadoc, [Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) return a pseudo random  and (approximately) uniform distributed number within the range.

So when you don't strict accuracy you may use it. Otherwise search for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this trivial code and see for yourself

```
    for (int ran = 0; ran < 10; ran++) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        System.out.println(random);
    }
```

Output in my case

> 2 2 0 2 1 0 0 0 2 1

Answer (score 0):

First, I must point that your question title is not that clear. Safe can mean various thing. In this case I think you mean safety of algorithm of your code, not security nor only Math.random().

Unfortunately, your code is not algorithmically safe. Even if Math.random is safe, Your code has always positive possibility on running at any time: roughly speaking it means there are no guarantee that your code ends in finite time.

Assume you are taking random number among 4 numbers. If you are drawing random number *excluding* right before number, you're actually not drawing from 4 numbers: it's 3. I suggest another method:

```
int prevInt = -1;

private int randomInt() {
    if (prevInt == -1) {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        //generate random numbers between 0 to 3 inclusive
    } else if
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        random = (random >= prevint) ? (random + 1) % 4 : random;
    }

    prevInt = random;
    return random;
}

private void resetRandom() {
    prevInt = -1;
    //use when you want to reset information that you have 'before' result.
}
```

This algorithm ends within finite time. Concern about whether Math.Random() itself is dangerous or whatever will be explained by other nice guys.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is safe but we never know what is going to happen, so we can simply multiply Math.random two times to maintain a good safety

`int random = (int) (Math.random() * Math.random() * 3);`